# Почему нет запятой, закрывающей деепричастный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация

**Вера всю себя изгрызла, приводя эти доводы в плюс — в минусе был всего один, зато какой!**

Мне кажется, что **современные авторы перестали ставить запятую в подобных случаях**. Это вроде бы не по правилам, но тем не менее так. Чем-то им мешает эта запятая, может быть, структура предложения хуже читается,   искажается как-то. **В чем тут дело?**

Answer (score 1):

Запятая в подразумеваемом месте (перед тире) и мне помешала бы - вынесением вставки с "минусом" за пределы деепричастного оборота, в то время как она относится *исключительно* к его содержанию (перекликаются "плюс" с "минусом"). Второе "штатное" тире вставки (она здесь распространена согласованным восклицанием) приходится здесь на конец предложения, поэтому оно не требуется, как и закрывающая оборот (вместе со вставкой) запятая.

Comment: Вы это так читаете, думаете, что это вставка?! А по-моему, это типичное БСП со значением сопоставления: Вера всю себя изгрызла, приводя эти доводы в плюс, в то время как  в минусе был всего один (довод), зато какой! Или так: ... в минусе же был всего один, зато какой!  Там же явная пауза, которая делит предложение на две части.

Comment: Прихожу к выводу, что вариант со вставкой тоже возможен. Тогда присоединительное предложение  (вставка) относится только к деепричастному обороту, и интонация у вариантов разная. Вот как одна-единственная запятая может передавать  оттенки смысла.  Всё-таки русская пунктуация - это  нечто удивительное, ее потенциальные возможности еще мало нами поняты.

Answer (score 1):

Поделюсь восприятием простого читателя. Встретив начало деепричастного оборота, мой мозг подсознательно переходит в режим ожидания запятой, символизирующей его (оборота) окончание. Вставка в виде целого предложения, да еще **в конце** деепричастного оборота — вместо ожидаемой запятой, — сбивает с толку. При первом прочтении восприятое было таким:  *приводя эти доводы "в плюс — в минус"*.

Comment: А вы согласны, что здесь возможны два варианта, и тогда какой Вам ближе? Я сначала была уверена, что запятую опустили исходя из современной моды. Такой вариант напрашивался естественным образом  (хотя бы из чувства равновесия объема текста и его содержания), и семантика просматривалась.  Но если это вставка, то тоже интересно. Это значит, что деепричастный оборот фактически закончен, а дальше идет интонация второго плана (вставочная), то есть мы  меняем темп речи, немного снижаем тональность, говорим как бы в сторону. Как Вам такой вариантик?

Comment: При постановке запятой мне начинает казаться, что "минус" относится не к деепричастному обороту, который лишь характеризует основное действие, а к самому действию, и что именно он, а не настойчиво приводившийся в аргументы "плюс", каким-то образом объясняет факт "полного самоизгрызания".